# Upgrading Django 1.11 to 2.2 - Crispy form troubles

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-2.2

I've recently upgraded a project from Django 1.11 to 2.2, alongside upgrading all the necessary packages and python 3.5 to 3.7. I've managed to fix everything that needed to be changed to upgrade to 2.2 django.

Among other packages I've also upgraded **django-crispy-forms** from **1.6 to 1.9** to be compatible with Django 2.2.

The problem I am facing is that, my **SplitDateTimeWidget** I am using in all crispy forms across the project is not displaying properly. It is not utilizing bootstrap3 style as display below:
 [image: crispy forms and djnago split date time widget]

Has anyone else faced with this issue when upgrading and what are the workoarounds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem If anyone faces the same situation.

New version did not include class **"form-control"** on an input field. I changed my widget to:

```
class TimepieceSplitDateTimeWidget(forms.SplitDateTimeWidget):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('date_format', DATE_FORM_FORMAT)
    kwargs['attrs'] = {'class': 'form-control',}  # ADDED THIS
    super(TimepieceSplitDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And is now working as it should.